# Can we change the name of WEB-INF

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, web-inf

may i know if i can change the name of WEB-INF folder in any tomcat webapp. If no, then why as there is context.xml file in tomcat conf folder which contain the path of watchedresource. I tried renaming it but it doesn't work. Can you please tell me what is the reason to provide    `<WatchedResource>newWebInf/web.xml</WatchedResource>` this tag in context.xml file if renaming is just not working. Or is there any other way to rename WEB-INF folder.

PS: I dont have any requirment related to this. I am just trying out the things. Please don't answer why and where you want this.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't rename the `WEB-INF` folder. It's hard specified in the [Servlet API specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/index.html).

The point of `<WatchedResource>` component is to specify the webapp-relative path of a file which Tomcat must monitor for changes in order to auto-reload the entire webapp. This defaults indeed to `WEB-INF/web.xml`, but it can also be another file, such as `index.jsp` or something else. The whole point is **not** that you can rename the `WEB-INF/web.xml`, but that you can specify a different file to monitor for changes.

Comment: ohh is it...Thanks, i was not aware of this. I'll mark your answer.